# Is is possible to integrate Joomla and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, joomla, content-management-system

I have learned Codeigniter (which is a PHP framework) and now I want to use a CMS to build my website. Classes which I found in Codigniter were very useful, now I want to use them in my website developed with CMS (e.g., Joomla).

Is there anyway to integrate CMS and PHP framework or what should I do in this case. Please guide me I am pretty confused about it.

Comment: I would catch the 404 in joomla and boot CI from there.  Then you have all joomla functionality and CI takes over if there is no joomla page.. Rename CI `index.php` to `index-ci.php` and `include 'index-ci.php'`

Comment: Not a fan of Joomla. WordPress is even much nicer. BTW, CodeIgniter is very nice too!

Comment: Joomla have its own framework  https://github.com/joomla/joomla-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enjoy using CodeIgniter (which I do), and you also want CMS functionality, you might like the following CMS, built on CodeIgniter: [Ionize CMS](http://ionizecms.com/).

Directly from the **Ionize CMS** website:

> The Ionize CMS uses CodeIgniter, a powerful and lightweight PHP framework. For CodeIgniter developpers, starting developping on Ionize will be really easy as building a CI application !

(and yes, this is copy-paste from their website, including misspellings...)