# CodeIgniter router for joomla sef urls?

Tags: codeigniter, joomla, codeigniter-routing

I wish to create a front-end for joomla using CodeIgniter. I prefer to make my own front-end that reads joomla database and I had my own "framework" to accomplish this, this is because I feel that joomla front-end is too heavy for high traffic websites, because it needs to accommodate for so many user needs, at the end you would really only use a small percentage of what joomla has to offer, yet a lot of unneeded core modules load and when you have a website with 300k visits per day, every bit of resource counts. And I like joomla because of its back-end and database structure.

Anyway, I'm looking to standardize a framework for joomla front-end using CodeIgniter instead of my own messy php code, the main issue for me is the ci router. In joomla I set sef url like these:

```
websitex.com/
websitex.com/category.html
websitex.com/category/subcat/123-alias.html
```

I'm looking for a router override that would allow me to process those urls. Basically, if any of the params has a number, then its for sure an article. If it doesn't, and its not index.php then its for sure a category or subcategory (if it exists).

And if I write this:

```
websitex.com/123 [OR]
websitex.com/category/123-alias.html
```

It would display the article with id 123. At least that's how it works in joomla and its what I'm trying to achieve here.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks in advance.

ADDED:
OK @ImranQamer comment left me thinking. What if I try to do it with conventional CI router? So I tried, and came up with this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller/index";
$route['index'] = "controller/index";
$route[':num'] = "controller/article";
$route['(:any)/:num'] = "controller/article";
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/section";
```

I think it may work. I've run some tests and so far so good.

First and second line, if nothing is specified OR index.suffix (index.html) is the URI, then it goes to my controller index method.
Third line, if URI is a number (eg: /123.html) then it routes to controller/article.
Fourth line needs more testing, but apparently it will grab any URI that ends with a number (or number + suffix) and route it to controller/article. Still needs another rule to let article's title alias to be put in the URI (eg: /category/123-hello.html)
And last line, will treat the URI as one of the categories/section of the joomla site. In this controller though, I'm going to need to check if submitted URI corresponds to an existing section, in which case it gets displayed, otherwise, redirected to 404.

I'm gonna test this out for a while, but looks good so far.

Comment: u studied CI routing?

Comment: @ImranQamer What do you mean? I know CI router doesn't work "as is" for this. I need to modify it, I'm just looking for some guidance.

Comment: Joomla is a completely different frame work to codeigniter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261981/is-is-possible-to-integrate-joomla-and-codeigniter

Comment: I use Joomla only for backend (eg administrator) and its database structure. I developed my own frontend for joomla which loads articles, modules and so on, but I'm looking to convert my frontend to codeigniter and I needed help with the routing. However I think I've solved my question, just doing some more tests before I close it.